# Finding the extension in a string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, string

The question I'm asking about: [image]

I'm trying to find the acceleration for the particle and I need to find an expression for the tension and fiction first. I managed to do the friction part but when I was trying to find out how far past the equilibrium position the particle was and how far it had been extended I got a little confused. If we split the string into two sections we get two section of 0.25m. The midpoint (equilibrium position) would be 0.25m from A. Now since the natural length is 0.5m I evaluated the tension to be $T=\frac{\lambda}{l}x=\frac{10}{0.5}0.25=5 N$. However, when I did this calculation I wasn't sure if my value for the natural length,l, was right since 0.5m is the natural length of the string not the section with length 0.25m. This then made me ask if my method was right to begin with. So my question is if my natural length is wrong and I need to somehow find the natural length of the 0.25m section from A to the equilibrium position or whether my method is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of question is often most easily solved using conservation of energy : the initial KE of the particle = PE stored in the string at maximum extension + work done against friction during the extension.